# Phonegap build globalization plugin "Class not found" error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I have been trying to unravel the various documentation examples for using the globalization plugin of PhoneGapBuild (3.0).

In my config.xml I have :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
```

at the top of my index.html i have:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script> 
<script src="globalization.js"></script>
```

and at the bottom I have:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function (e) {            
        navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
                function (language) { alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n'); },
                function (error) { alert(error); }
            );
    }, "false");
</script>
```

when I upload the app to phonegap build and run it on a new HTC One, the failure callback fires and alerts:

"class not found"

I feel there is something fundamental I am missing, but am at a loss

Also, when I look at the "plugins" tab of the phonegap build project page, globalization is listed.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but maybe this directive is required in your **config.xml**

```
<feature name="Globalization">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.globalization.Globalization" />
</feature>
```

Try to look the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization)

Comment: I'm having this same issue and that tag is in my config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to remove the android platform, re-add it and then recompile everything.